# How to embed instagram images with a short code snippet?

Tags: embed, instagram-api

I'm looking for a possibility to embed instagram images to my website.

I tried the embed code from the "..." menu, but this code is way to long if I wanna use it a lot of times. Beside this, it doesnt work for me properly anyways.

I also found the old embed variant via iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.instagram.com/p/CJj1fHYpm7v/embed/" width="400px" height="610px" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" ></iframe>
```

That's definitly something I prefer since it's just a little code. But I'm not sure if this is still officially supported.

I also read something about the API for it, but that solution is really confusing to me... not sure if this work for me.

So I wonder if anybody can tell me about other solutions how to embed images quick and easy, if the iframe solution is still a good way to go and other info which helps me to realize the plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data (urls and ids) in json format from that url:

```
https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?limit=25&fields=thumbnail_url,permalink,media_url,media_type&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

- `limit` controls how many items you get

You will get a response that looks like this:

```json
{
   "data": [
      {
         "permalink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/CJ54xbvlkY_/",
         "media_url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/137643256_251304213045078_6123570534757271423_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&ccb=2&_nc_sid=8ae9d6&_nc_ohc=awl9dH0LssMAX9FBG6G&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&oh=fae6ccda08c19a6617dd5b1acf985fbe&oe=6025F7CC",
         "media_type": "IMAGE",
         "id": "18061654837271107"
      }
  ]
}
```

To create an access token follow the steps in the documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

A simple example (without errorhandling ect.) how you could use this (via php) would be:

```php
<?php
  $oJson = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?limit=25&fields=thumbnail_url,permalink,media_url,media_type&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'));

  foreach($oJson->data as $entry): ?>
    <a href="<?= $entry->permalink ?>">
      <img src="<?=$entry->media_url ?>">
    </a>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```